# image is not setting as background image using angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript, background-image

i have a list of `cards` to be displayed in a `component`. On each card there is a `cover-image` whose url is coming from server and there is a `ngFor` in my `component.html` like this

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url('+row.companyId?.coverUrl+')'" class="img-area">
</div>
<div class="card-content-area">
   <p class="card-title cursor-pointer" (click)="navigateToCOmpany(row)">{{row.companyId.name}}</p>
   <div class="card-description-area">
      <p class="site-text">{{row.offer_desc}}</p>
   </div>
        <a (click)="referralClick(row, i)" class="site-btn show-desktop-block">Get referral link</a>
        <a (click)="referralClick(row, i)" class="site-link-mobile show-mobile-block"><i class="fa fa-link mobile-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> Get Referral link</a>
</div>
```

Here is how i am getting url in my html. I am attaching `chrome inspect element` result to show that in html i am getting url but image is not displaying.

[image]

Please identify the mistake that what i am doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked the displayed URL is working fine>

Comment: yes i have checked.  It's working fine.

Comment: do you get a specific message in your console about sanitizing a link?

Comment: No, i am not getting any kind of warning regarding link sanitizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try add some height and width to my div

try with random values:

```
.img-area{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

Comment: yes you are right. It's working. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: can you guide me about one another thing?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari sure tell me

Comment: I want to check if `row.companyId?.coverUrl` is exist to put that url in the backgorund property and if not exist so apply hard coded url like `./assets/img/abc.jpg` so according to my code how can i do that?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari can you make another post I will happy to help I'm just working on this kind of thing and I think I have the answer thanks in advance

Comment: i have posted a new question. Please respond on that. here is the url of that question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741176/how-can-i-check-if-else-condition-in-ngstyle-background-property-using-angular7

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with ngStyle

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + row.companyId?.coverUrl + ')'}" class="img-area">
```

Comment: try to see if you are getting the imag url by printing somewhere {{row.companyId.coverUrl}}

Comment: did you see the attached picture in my question? i am getting url in inspect element