# How can i check if else condition in ngstyle background property using angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-style

i have a list of cards to be displayed in a `component`. On each card there is a `cover-image` whose url is coming from server and there is a ngFor in my `component.html` like this

```
 <div [style.background-image]="'url('+row.companyId?.coverUrl+')'" class="img-area">
 </div>
 <div class="card-content-area">
  <p class="card-title cursor-pointer" (click)="navigateToCOmpany(row)">{{row.companyId.name}}</p>
 <div class="card-description-area">
    <p class="site-text">{{row.offer_desc}}</p>
 </div>
    <a (click)="referralClick(row, i)" class="site-btn show-desktop-block">Get referral link</a>
    <a (click)="referralClick(row, i)" class="site-link-mobile show-mobile-block"><i class="fa fa-link mobile-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> Get Referral link</a>
 </div>
```

I am getting cover-images in `row.companyId.coverUrl`. I want to check if `row.companyId.coverUrl` exist so put the incoming `Url` but url is not coming form the api so it should put the hardcoded url in background like `./assets/img/abc.jpg`

How can i do that?

Comment: no problem last solution is I think what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try on the subscribe stage:

```
...subscribe(
  (data:any) => {
    this.row = data;
   if (!this.row){
     this.row = {
       companyId: {
         coverUrl: './assets/img/abc.jpg'
       }
     }
   }
   else if (!this.row.companyId){
     this.row.companyId = {
       coverUrl: './assets/img/abc.jpg'
     }
   }
   else if (!this.row.companyId.coverUrl)
       this.row.companyId.coverUrl = './assets/img/abc.jpg';
  }
)
```

if you still have an URL and wan't to check if the image can be loaded I think you will need a `http.get('imageURL').subsribe()` then do the test if it responds well.

I highly suggest you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287474/onerror-event-using-background-url) too

so this would do something like

in your ts:

```
localImg = "/assets/img/abc.jpg"
```

in your html:

```
[style.background]="'url('+row.companyId?.coverUrl+'), url(' + localImg +')'"
```

**not tested**

Comment: No, i am setting div's background image. So i can't do that. Read my code carefully.

Comment: oh sorry I will try find a solution

Comment: i wondering to do it in `html` :D. Any how thanks i will do like this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular pipes exactly fit this scenario.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'coverImage'
})
export class CoverImagePipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(row: any): string {
    if (row != null && row.companyId != null) {
      return `url('${row.companyId.coverUrl}')`;
    }
    return `url('./assets/img/abc.jpg')`;
  }
}
```

and then consume this pipe in HTML

```html
<div [style.background-image]="row | coverImage" class="img-area"></div>
```